# How to change a dataype CLOB TO VARCHAR2(sql)

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl, clob, varchar2

Table: customers

```
ID      NAME             DATATYPE
NUMBER  VARCHAR2(100)    CLOB
```

I want to change the `DATA` column from `CLOB` to `VARCHAR2(1000)

I have try `ALTER TABLE customers MODIFY DATA VARCHAR2 (1000)` also

`ALTER TABLE customers MODIFY (DATA VARCHAR2 (1000))`

also

```
alter table customers  modify
(data VARCHAR2(4000))
```

those normally works if the datatype is not a clob but I am getting a `ORA-22859` because I am using oracle toad/apex.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You may try this:

1. Add a new column as varchar2

   `alter table my_table add (new_column varchar2(1000));`
2. UPDATE CLOB name to varchar2 column;

   `update my_table set new_column=dbms_lob.substr(old_column,1000,1);`

After **testing your data**:

3. DROP CLOB column

   `alter table my_table drop column old_column`
4. Rename varchar2 column to CLOB column name

   `alter table my_table rename column new_column to old_column`

Comment: lol i was thinking the same but I can't do that. They should be away to change `clob` datatype

Comment: `They should be away to change clob datatype`..What does that mean?

Comment: it means changing clob to varachar2 or number same as you can change a varachar2(100) to varchar2(1000) or vaachar2 to number, etc

Comment: you want to me `add` a new colum while I am trying to change the existing colum `datatype` from clob to `varchar2`

Comment: @PHPnoob:- I understand that but that would be the easiest one. Check this related thread: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5948/how-to-replace-a-clob-column-by-a-varchar24000-column