# Entity Framework 6 Migration to change CLOB column to VARCHAR in Oracle

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to change a CLOB column to VARCHAR(2000) in oracle using EF 6 migration. When EF scaffold the migration file, I have the following line of code in my *Up()* method:

```
AlterColumn("MTA.PLAN_SHEETS", "PLANSHEET_NAME", c => c.String(maxLength: 2000, unicode: false));
```

When I run the migration I get this error

> invalid modification of columns

I know that in Oracle we cannot change a Clob to Varchar directly:
[How to change a dataype CLOB TO VARCHAR2(sql)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19841947/how-to-change-a-dataype-clob-to-varchar2sql)

What is the best approach to change a Clob to Varchar in Entity Framework migration?

Comment: Does anyone have an answer to this question?  I inadvertently allowed EF6 to create CLOBs instead of NVARCHAR2.  Now I need to change them to VARCHAR2, but I don't want to lose the data that's in the columns now

Comment: You will need to do this in 2 or 3 migrations using the basic steps in the link above. First add the varchar2 column, rename the CLOB column and add script command to copy the data. Then you could do a 2nd migration to rename the varchar2 to the original CLOB column name. Test it and when you are happy add a 3rd migration to drop the CLOB.

Answer (score 1):

There is the same problem in probably all RDBMSs.
I always use a code similar to this and I think (I'm quite sure) that this is the only way to do it.

```
AddColumn("MTA.PLAN_SHEETS", "TMP_COLUMN", c => c.String(maxLength: 2000, unicode: false));
Sql(@"UPDATE MTA.PLAN_SHEETS SET TMP_COLUMN = PLANSHEET_NAME");
DropColumn("MTA.PLAN_SHEETS", "PLANSHEET_NAME");
RenameColumn("MTA.PLAN_SHEETS", "TMP_COLUMN", "PLANSHEET_NAME");
```

Comment: It's a migration question so these steps will be run in a batch. Easy way is to run multiple migrations. Another way is to use an [extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17105716/adding-go-statements-to-entity-framework-migrations) to insert 'GO' statements after each.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

**dbms_lob.substr( clob_column, for_how_many_bytes, from_which_byte );**

for example :

**select dbms_lob.substr( x, 4000, 1 ) from T;**